# How can I make this generic

Tags: .net, vb.net, generics, mvvm

I have a bunch of ViewModel classes, Q001ViewModel, Q002ViewModel, ..., QnnnViewModel.  These all inherit from VMBase.

I also have a set of Subs ShowQnnn, ShowQnnn, ..., ShowQnnn.  An example is:

```
    Private Sub ShowQ001()
        Dim workspace As Q001ViewModel = _
            CType(Me.Workspaces.FirstOrDefault(Function(vm) vm.GetType() Is GetType(Q001ViewModel)), Q001ViewModel)

        If workspace Is Nothing Then
            workspace = New Q001ViewModel(_dbc)
            Me.Workspaces.Add(workspace)
        End If

        Me.SetActiveWorkspace(workspace)
    End Sub
```

Workspaces is an ObservableCollection of VMBase.

The ShowQnnn procedures are used to display a ViewModel.  The point is that a new QnnnViewModel will be added to the workspaces collection only if one of that type does not already exist.

Is there a way to turn then ShowQnnn procedures into one generic version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry but I don't know VB.Net syntax enough regarding generics (feel free to edit my answer with the VB.Net version), so i'll answer in C#.

If the constructors take different arguments the solution would look like :

```
void ShowQxxx<T>(Func<T> constructor)
    where T : VMBase
{
    var workspace = (T)(Workspaces.FirstOrDefault(vm => vm is T);

    if (workspace == null)
    {
        workspace = constructor();
        Workspaces.Add(workspace)
    }

    SetActiveWorkspace(workspace)
}

...

ShowQxxx(() => new Q001ViewModel(_dbc));
```

Otherwise you could simplify even more using reflection :

```
void ShowQxxx<T>()
    where T : VMBase
{
    var workspace = (T)(Workspaces.FirstOrDefault(vm => vm is T);

    if (workspace == null)
    {
        var ctor = typeof(T).GetConstructor(new [] { typeof(MyDataBaseType) });
        workspace = (T)(ctor.Invoke(_dbc));
        Workspaces.Add(workspace)
    }

    SetActiveWorkspace(workspace)
}

...

ShowQxxx<Q001ViewModel>();
```

Comment: looks just great.  Will test anbd report back with VB.Net version

Comment: didn't you leave out the type in the first option, so it should be ShowQxxx<Q001ViewModel>(() => new Q001ViewModel(_dbc)); ?

Comment: I leave out the type in the call as the C# compiler in recent versions is able to infer it from the result type of the lambda

Comment: OK, that works in VB.Net too - so i've updated the VB version below.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Here is the VB version

```
    Private Sub ShowQxxx(Of T As VMBase)(constructor As Func(Of T))
        Dim workspace As T = _
            CType(Me.Workspaces.FirstOrDefault(Function(vm) vm.GetType() Is GetType(T)), T)

        If workspace Is Nothing Then
            workspace = constructor()
            Me.Workspaces.Add(workspace)
        End If

        Me.SetActiveWorkspace(workspace)
    End Sub
....

    ShowQxxx(Function() New Q001ViewModel(_dbc))
```